# Data from the Second Table repeats when using Left Outer Join

Tags: mysql, sql

Good Morning Everyone. I`m creating an MySQL Command to 
make this output.

[image]

but when I tried it the Output is this.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
select purchorder.PONo,purchorder.ItemCode,purchorder.Description,
purchorder.OrderQty,
receiving.ItemCode,receiving.Description,Receiving.ReceivedQty from purchorder
LEFT OUTER JOIN Receiving on receiving.RIno = purchorder.RINumber where 
purchorder.PONo = 'P0239ROI'
Group BY purchorder.ItemCode;
```

Table PurchOrder

[image]

Table Rceiving

[image]

How can I achieve the Output above? (With the Yellow Header)

Here is the Latest Possible answer

[image]
TYSM

Comment: Please share data of `purchorder`  and `Receiving` separately with `PONo = 'P0239ROI'`.

Comment: will you have same item code appear more than once in either purchorder and Receiving?  Anyway, it is almost impossible to give a proper answer without knowing your data model.

Comment: You are selecting columns which do not either appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or are aggregates.  This is a no-no.  _Which_ records do you want to use for those non aggregate columns?

Comment: I will update my post Sir`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that just remove your `group by` clause and add `receiving.RIno` in `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    purchorder.PONo,
    purchorder.ItemCode,
    purchorder.Description,
    purchorder.OrderQty,
    receiving.RIno,
    receiving.ItemCode,
    receiving.Description,
    Receiving.ReceivedQty
FROM purchorder
LEFT JOIN Receiving ON receiving.RIno = purchorder.RINumber
AND Receiving.ItemCode = purchorder.ItemCode
WHERE purchorder.PONo = 'P0239ROI'
```

Comment: Sir the data looks different from what I needed, Please see the Latest Edited Post

Comment: @PaulEdwardSanGabrielPagente You also should add `Receiving.ItemCode = purchorder.ItemCode` in `ON` clause. Updated my answer, check it please.

Comment: Sir It Looks funny but I think the first after the Edited Post looks Correct

Comment: TY Sir for the Code. :)

Comment: Really a Great Help. :)